# US Visa Application Single or Married?

Tags: visas, usa

I am getting married to my partner who is a US citizen. According to US laws, I will be married. However, India does not yet recognize same-sex marriages.

If/when I fill out a DS-160 for a visa renewal and am going to India (I am currently residing in the USA) to renew my visa, would I fill in "single" or "married"?

I assume married, because technically the DS-160 is for the US and it recognizes the wedding. However, my Indian passport would continue to say "single", and I'm not entirely sure how that would be taken.

Comment: What country are you getting married in? Will your marriage be recognised according to the laws of that country?

Comment: @JoeMalt I'll be getting married in the US.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you’re married (under US law), you’re married (under US law). What your Indian passport says is immaterial to that. The fact that it doesn’t match is not unusual (people don’t make sure to get new passports right after they get married), won’t present an insurmountable problem (US immigration would give you a chance to explain the situation), and likely won’t present an issue at all (most passports don’t even mention martial status, and it’s not the sort of thing US immigration is looking for in a passport).